# Why is my VSTO 4.0 project building so slowly

Tags: vsto

I have created a VSTO project that is absolutely bare bones for OL 2010
it just one button on the main Outlook window
I am using VS 2010 Enterprise and Windows 7
this a pretty performant machine ( 8 gigs ram quad proc etc )
and yet building this project is  taking for ever ( 5 minuted forever )
I can only guess VS is taking forever to check something not sure what
Thanks

Comment: Are you running as an Admin user (e.g. UAC disabled)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi rahul u might want to check any ram leakages in the code but usually VS is a fail safe program so i think if you can share the code here and the purpose of it then someone might be able to help you..

Comment: I compiled using msbuild. The whole thing is getting stuck here Deleting File: bin\Debug\CPAOutlook2010Addin.dll.manifest.pregam. I have zero idea what this file is or why it should matter. Urgh

Comment: Ok basically you might want to check the security settings in the Outlook trustcenter to make sure that it is accepting the add-ins and what not security settings so that VS2010 is not blocked and need to go through all the proper security channels,which it will take time no matter how fast is the computer..and another thing that you might want to do is close the outlook application completly by making sure in the Task Manager

Comment: do you have admin permission on your machine?